# I connected my earphones now my speakers do not work

Tags: sound

I connected my earphones on my Laptop and the music played through the earphones.

Now, when I unplugged the earphones, the speakers did not work at all. I restarted the system, still, the speakers do not work.

The sound only comes through earphones when they are plugged in. When they are plugged out, there is no sound from the speakers.

Comment: When you go to `Settings`→`Sound` and try plugging in and unplugging the earphones, do you notice a change? It should switch between `Headphones` and `Speakers`. Volume and mute should be preserved and restored for either one.

Comment: I unplug it, but it still shows headphones.

Comment: What about shutdown the computer and start it again? I found my laptop speakers do not work if I restart computer after using Windows, but if I shutdown and start it again - speakers sound works without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal and type `alsactl restore` then press enter, this should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings→Sound and force the selection of Speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I restart the computer from Windows into Elementary OS. No matter what I do the speakers would not work until I shut down the computer and start it again - reinstalling drivers, tuning settings - no change. Try to shut down and then check if speakers work again.